# Replace, Clean & Trim VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I m trying to:

1. Replace double spaces with single.
2. Clean
3. Trim

the same string and i use:

```
AmountI = Replace(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(.Cells(j, 9).Value)), "  ", " ")
```

I want to know if there is a specific order of those three VBA functions or the order does not play any role in the outcome.thanks for the help!

Comment: It should be pretty straightforward to try all the possible function orders on the same test string, and compare outputs... Have you tried this? What's the test string which needs cleaned?

Comment: @Olly i have a Excel Document with a column with descriptions downloaded from website (via copy paste) and i will loop this column to clean from extra characters scraped from the website, remove double spacing or extra spaces in both beginning or ending of the string,

Comment: My point is, there are only 6 different ways to order those three functions - it would be trivial to test all 6 combinations against a single known test string, to compare the outputs, and ensure you select a function order which will return your expected results.

Comment: This is the first think i did before i post.what i want is to ensure that there is not any standardize way to combine this three functions.

Comment: vba.trim doesn't remove double spacing, only leading/trailing spaces. You need the worksheet version Application.Trim or WorksheetFunction.Trim to remove interim double spaces.

Comment: @Jeeped i try to replace double spacing with single spacing and i use trim only for leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: ... and what if you start with a triple space? Better to get rid of replace and use application.trim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vba.trim doesn't remove double spacing, only leading/trailing spaces. You need the worksheet version Application.Trim or WorksheetFunction.Trim to remove interim double spaces.

If you have triple spacing, a single Replace will leave you with a double space. Application.Trim will not.

You don't want Clean to process characters (i.e. spaces) that you are going to remove anyways so Trim first.

.Value2 (without currency or date information) is marginally faster processing when you don't have currency or date data; you have a string so use .Value2.

```
AmountI = Application.Clean(Application.Trim(.Cells(j, 9).Value2))
```

Comment: clean doesn't affect spaces, only ascii <=31

Comment: ... but it still has to determine whether to deal with it or not. Cleaning 1K characters with 990 spaces cannot be faster than cleaning 10 characters with no lead/trailing or double spaces and in either event, Trim still has to its work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 AmountI = Trim(Replace(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cells(j, 9).text), "  ", " "))
```

My logic is: 
  1  .Text is faster than .Value
  2  Clean may close up two spaces by removing a non-printing char between them, so do this before...
  3 Turn double spaces to single with replace, then
  4 Remove leading and trailing spaces

Comment: If the cell has left indent formatting, .Text will show that leading space and have to process it. .Value2 is the raw underlying text value with no other considerations.

Comment: `.Value2` is also faster than `.Text`